# How to detect when Widget gains or loses focus - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm building an app with some Widgets (in ListView) which need differnt behaviors depending on if it is focused or not. This is the point : I want to change Widget's color when it gain focuus or loses it when user scrolls

Comment: you may find this useful https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html